# Do I understand MVC wrong or are this controls (by Syncfusion) just very bad?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, syncfusion

since the last few weeks we are using the Synfusion MVC controls.
https://www.syncfusion.com/products/aspnetmvc

Even I have experience with ASP.Net since a bunch of years, my MVC experience are only 6 month. So I looked into this controls and missing a bunch of things which either means I am having a missunderstanding at MVC or this controlls seem to be bad - very bad.

One example: the progress bar.
In the MVC-controls we have a reference here:        http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/aspnetmvc/Documents/overview36.htm
This progress bar seems have nothing to do with MVC - I can't even find a single method for binding a model to this progress bar, having control by my controller or even bind a single piece of data through my backend to my view to this progress bar.

It feels wrong.

Even there it seems to be a bit worse: Syncfusion seems to had a project called "MVC classic" which seems to be the previous version (first version) of MVC controls from them. 
Here you can find a reference to the progress bad in MVC classic:
http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/tools/ProgressBar/ThroughModel
There they have something "like" a databinding - you can have a model for a progress bad with a given set of data, BUT you can't bind it directly with the model on the viewside - you have to pass it by matching name/id in the ViewData.

This feels even more wrong, especily because that was the "previous" version of the mvc-grid...

Can you please tell me: Do I have a huge missunderstanding of basic knowlegde of MVC here or are this controls just this bad?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation and demos, I see NO problems with it :)

Seriously, for me what I read about the ProgressBar makes sense and seems to be easy to use. I do not see the part that is causing you a problem.

Perhaps you could tell us more about the issues you are having, but based on the lack experience you have with MVC, I say that might be the explanation, but please give us more insights about your question.

Comment: Okay, the problem for me is, that in the MVC-Progress bar, there seems no way to databind a model to this progressbar... As far as I understand MVC I would write a ProgressBarDataModel with e.g. the percentage to display and bind it to the view something like @Html.EJ().ProgressBar(MyModel.ProgressBarDataModel) - then, whenever the Model changes, the ProgressBar will change...

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit more info here http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/web/progressbar/events . But still no way to bind directly to data. And, as I understand, not possible. You need to update the page in some way. The right way to do it will be Ajax.